# C# Send byte[] to server, decrypt content and send it as byte[] back to client

Tags: c#, sockets, encryption, client-server, file-transfer

My problem is the following:

I have a client/server application connected over sockets. My client´s task is to send a file byte-wise to the server. The server gets the bytes, decrypt them, send it back to the client and he writes them in a new file on disk.

I get everytime a serverside exception (System.Security.Cryptography.Exception: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed) at this line of code: plaintext = sr.ReadToEnd();

Could somebody help me to solve my problem?

Here is the decryption code:

```
public byte[] Dec(byte[] content, byte[] Key, byte[] IV, int fileLength, string filepath, int chunkSize, int bytesToRead)
    {
        byte[] contentDec;
        string plaintext = null;
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

        using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijAlg.Key = Key;
            rijAlg.IV = IV;

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);


            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(content))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cs))
                    {
                        plaintext = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                    }
                    contentDec = encoding.GetBytes(plaintext);
                }
            }
        }
        return contentDec;
    }
```

Here is my encryption code:

```
    public byte[] Enc(byte[] content,byte[] Key, byte[] IV, int fileLength,string filepath, int chunkSize, int bytesToRead)
    {
        byte[] contentEnc;
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
        using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijAlg.Key = Key;
            rijAlg.IV = IV;
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(cs))
                    {
                        sw.Write(content);
                    }
                    contentEnc = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        return contentEnc;
    }
```

On client side I call encryption method like this

```
        int chunkSize = 1024;
        byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkSize];
        using (FileStream fileReader = new FileStream(plainPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (FileStream filewriter = new FileStream(pathEncrypt, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileReader))
        using (RijndaelManaged myRijndael = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            myRijndael.GenerateKey();
            myRijndael.GenerateIV();
            Key = myRijndael.Key;
            IV = myRijndael.IV;
            int bytesToRead = (int)fileReader.Length;
            do
            {
                chunk = service.Enc(binaryReader.ReadBytes(chunkSize), Key, IV,(int)fileReader.Length, 
                    fileReader.Name, chunkSize, bytesToRead);
                filewriter.Write(chunk, 0, chunk.Length);
                bytesToRead -= chunkSize;
            } while (bytesToRead > 0);
        }
```

Key and IV are declared as private byte[]

On client side I call decryption method like this

```
        int chunkSize = 1024;
        byte[] chunk = new byte[chunkSize];
        using (FileStream fileReader = new FileStream(pathEncrypt, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        using (FileStream filewriter = new FileStream(pathDecrypt, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(fileReader))
        {
            int bytesToRead = (int)fileReader.Length;

            do
            {
                chunk = service.Dec(binaryReader.ReadBytes(chunkSize), Key, IV, (int)fileReader.Length, 
                    fileReader.Name, chunkSize, bytesToRead);
                filewriter.Write(chunk, 0, chunk.Length);
                bytesToRead -= chunkSize;
            } while (bytesToRead > 0);
        }
```

Edit: This is my connection establishment between client and server.

Server:
    var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service),
                       new Uri("net.pipe://localhost"));

```
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TiService),
                                new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "TestService");
        host.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Server connection established...");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Client:

```
var callback = new Callback();
var context = new InstanceContext(callback);
var pipeFactory =
new DuplexChannelFactory<TiService>(context,
new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/TestService"));

service = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
service.Connect();
```

Comment: Edit your question to include the encryption code too.

Comment: Edit my question

Comment: Your encryption code is not necessary correct as you are likely getting partial stream as result of calling `ToArray` before data committed...

Comment: And how can I fix this or bypass it?

Comment: You might need to explicitly set the padding strategy to fix this. See the answer to [this question on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d1788582-bf8c-43ec-a686-49647c359136/unexplained-cryptographicexception-padding-is-invalid?forum=netfxbcl)

Comment: @MarkusDeibel It doesn´t work. Everywhere I placed it I got the same error.

Comment: Interesting fact is that the output file has always the same 17 chars...

Comment: Does your code deal with ASCII plaintext, or arbitrary files? I just realized your decryptor actually treat the file as text file

Comment: I test the encryption/decryption with .txt files but it should be work with all files therefore I save files in byte[] and send it to the server..

Comment: Can you try creating a short file, say a .txt with only 5 character in it? Try saving the file as ANSI, Unicode, and UTF-8, because I can't replicate your error, I copied your code and ReadToEnd is run successfully, yet it will throw an error on FlushFinalBlock() for calling it twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem start from using [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.7.2) in the encryption. It's meant for writing Text file, not arbitrary file. When you call sw.Write(content), it simply call content.ToString(), which return "System.Byte[]", instead what you'd probably expect, each byte of the array. To fix it, simply write the CryptoStream, no need to use StreamWriter, like this :

```
using (var rijAlg = new AesCng())
{
    rijAlg.Key = Key;
    rijAlg.IV = IV;
    ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor();
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(content, 0, content.Length);               
        }
        contentEnc = ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

You probably noticed I used AesCng instead of RijndaelManaged. Why? Because it's much faster in my test, and unless you really need non-standard block, there's no benefit of using RijndaelManaged. Also, I use the parameterless CreateEncryptor because you already set the Key & IV on the previous lines anyway.

Same deal in the decryption. You shouldn't treat them as text, thus :

```
var buffer = new byte[content.Length]; //at first its size is actual size+padding

using (var rijAlg = new AesCng())
{
    rijAlg.Key = Key;
    rijAlg.IV = IV;

    ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor();

    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(content))
    {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            var actualSize = cs.Read(buffer, 0, content.Length);
            //we write the decrypted content to the buffer, and get the actual size

            Array.Resize(ref buffer, actualSize);
            //then we resize the buffer to the actual size
        }
    }
}
return buffer;
```

Also, your usage of the Enc and Dec is needlessly complex. It's already able to handle the whole file by itself. So to encrypt the file, simply use

```
var original = File.ReadAllBytes("originalPath");
var enc = Enc(original, rM.Key, rM.IV);
File.WriteAllBytes("encryptedPath", enc);
```

And to decrypt the file, just use

```
var enc = File.ReadAllBytes("encryptedPath");
var dec = Dec(enc, rM.Key, rM.IV);
File.WriteAllBytes("decryptedPath", dec);
```

As you can see, I throw away the fileLength,filepath, chunkSize, and bytesToRead on Enc & Dec, because your current code doesn't actually use them anyway. I've tried the code with short text file on ASCII, Unicode and UTF-8, and with large binary files, all encrypted & decrypted successfully with identical hash on the final decrypted files.

Edit :

Turning the code into direct filestream writing affair actually makes everything so much simpler.

```
public static void Transform(string source, string target, ICryptoTransform transf)
{
    var bufferSize = 65536;
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];


    using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (var targetStream = new FileStream(target, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(targetStream, transf, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                var bytesRead = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    cs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                } while (bytesRead != 0);
            }
        }

    }


}

public static void Enc(string source, byte[] Key, byte[] IV, string target)
{
    using (var rijAlg = new AesCng())
    {
        rijAlg.Key = Key;
        rijAlg.IV = IV;
        ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor();
        Transform(source, target, encryptor);
    }

}
public static void Dec(string source, byte[] Key, byte[] IV, string target)
{
    using (var rijAlg = new AesCng())
    {
        rijAlg.Key = Key;
        rijAlg.IV = IV;
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor();
        Transform(source, target, decryptor);
    }

}
```

Usage is :

```
Enc(@"originalPath", key, iv, @"encryptedPath");
Dec(@"encrypedPath", key, iv, @"decryptedPath");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I´ll test it but my question is: How does it look with big files > 10GB ? Therefore I need a solution to send it byte-wise to the server and don´t read all bytes (your code: var originial = FIle.ReadAllBytes("originalPath"); Or am I wrong with my idea?

Comment: I implemented the System.Security.Cryptography but my program don´t get the AesCng()...

Comment: Enc(original, rM.Key, rM.IV) ==> Where do you set rM and which Object is this?

Comment: If you don't get AesCng, perhaps you're pre .NET 4.6? Just replace with AesCryptoServiceProvider instead. As for rM, ignore them, just use your own key & iv as you've used originally

Comment: Thank you! Your answer works for me! But if I wanna encrypt a .jpg then I get the following Exception: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error writing to the pipe: The pipe is being closed. (232, 0xe8). How can I fix this?

Comment: I implemented your code which you wrote in edit. Therefore I get this exception: System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed

Comment: Edit: I tried PaddingMode.ANSIX923 , PaddingMode.ISO10126 , PaddingMode.PKCS7 , PaddingMode.None and PaddingMode.Zeros...Get everytime the padding Exception but the last one run successfully but the decrypt-file is nonsense.

Comment: Pipe being closed is because you're writing to a network socket right? Don't use FileStream then, use NetworkStream instead.

Comment: I should reaplace FileStream with NetworkStream in your Transform()-Method? Then I´ll get an error because I need an socket instance. But on the server I haven´t a socket instance. I´ll edit my first post with the connection from client to server.

Comment: Do you have a solution for my padding problem?

Comment: I've tried my code with smallish JPEG files, txt files, huge ISO files, none show any problem, but they're all reading & writing to *local files*. Your problem must be because your socket is closing for whatever reason. So this is no longer about "padding" problem, it's your socket that get closed in the middle of the process, and you'll get the error no matter what you choose. Does your code works *correctly* when sending files without encryption? Don't just test the content of small text, try sending huge files and compare their hashes too.

Comment: My code works until I want to decrypt the encrypted file. Sending the plainText.txt and getting the plainTextEncrypted.txt works fine. Also with my test-image works fine until i want to decrypt. So I think there is sth. wrong. I think it´s much easier to send the client a NetworkStream-Object with the reference of the file to encrypt/decrypt. Or not?

Comment: If you encrypt a local file to local file (no network used at all), is resulting file exactly the same (the hash) as when you encrypt to network? There's no such thing as "until I want to decrypt", I suspect the encrypted file is actually chopped by your network. The encrypted file should be identical or slightly larger than the original file.

Comment: If temporarily writing the file locally and sending them manually is not a problem, I'd use SFTP instead. Bonus point if all you want is sending the file securely, then SFTP on itself is enough, no need to encrypt & decrypting them separately.